# Capture 60fps on iOS to reduce motion blur

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, core-video, core-media

I need to reduce motion blur in my video, so I tried every `sessionPreset` on `AVCaptureSession` to get 60fps video capture but none of them seem to work. I found a few old threads that mention the 1280 preset would work on iOS 5, but I had no success with any preset on iOS 10 (iPhone 6).

It just fails when I try to configure `activeVideoMin/MaxFrameDuration` to 60fps.

The queried format also says it only supports a range between 2 to 30fps.

Is there really no way to capture 60fps (or reduce video motion blur) on iOS 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iphone 6 and 6 plus has tow device format. one for 1080p30 and another for 1080p60. When you set `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh`  it uses 1080p30.

To record vide with 60fps, iterate through `AVCaptureDevice` Formats, find the format you want and then set AVCaptureDevice `**setActiveFormat**` property instead of AVCaptureSession `setSessionPreset`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2409/_index.html